# View images in the login page

Tags: asp.net

All the users have to do the login before access to my site.
So i insert this code in web.config file:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
 <forms name="login" loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" defaultUrl="~/index.aspx"/>
</authentication>
<authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

It works but the login page is rendered without images..

How can i do?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the security on your image directory to allow unauthenticated users access. You can do that one of two ways:

1) You can add another Web.Config to the image directory that contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
  <system.web>
      <authorization>
         <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

2) Update the Web.Config in your root directory with a location-specific rule:

```
<location path="images/">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Either change should fix the problem.